# How to Set 'targets' Dynamically in columnDefs Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, datatables

I want to change the column sorting based upon the column name. I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.datatable_tri').dataTable({
 'columnDefs': [ { 'type': 'file-size', 'targets': 1 }  ],
    'aaSorting': [],
    'iDisplayLength': 50
  });
});
```

For many datatables, i have 3 or more, I Do not want to hard code the value for targets like 0 or 1...

I also tried using

```
'columnDefs': [ { 'type': 'file-size', 'title': 'SIZE' } ],
```

but it does'nt work.

PS : SIZE is the column header

Here is a fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/v07uxf35/3/

Comment: Still i am bit confuse to your question?

Answer (score 0):

`aaSorting` although still supported is a property of older version of DataTables 1.9.x. Newer version 1.10.x uses [order](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) property instead.

According to the documentation of `order` property and corresponding [columns.orderData](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) property, both require column index only.

If you don't want to use indexes in `targets`, use `columns` instead of `columnDef`. It makes code much more readable, since it doesn't require `targets`, only listing columns in sequential order as they appear in your table.

Comment: ??? sorry but may be you did'nt anderstand my request.
I have so many tables, each table contains a file-size column, I'm using the plug-in File-size of datatables to sort this column. the exemple I put above, is for one table, where the target of this column is '1'. I don't want to use aaSorting, or order, I defined a function and call it like this : 'columnDefs': [ { 'type': 'file-size', 'targets': 1 }  ],

Comment: I understood, that you didn't want to use indexes in targets. See my suggestion in third paragraph. Alternatively, you can set class attribute for `<th>` tags and use that name as a target, see documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets).

Comment: Thasks @Gyrocode.com, **class attribute** on `<th>` solve my problem!